# Python: Log in to a website using Requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to use Requests module to login into a site and get the html of the landing page. I am new to these stuff and I can't find a decent tutorial for this.
Here's the information that I have about that page
HTML of the form for login  (url:http://14.139.251.99:8080/jopacv06/html/checkouts)

```
<FORM NAME="form" METHOD="POST" ACTION="./memberlogin" onsubmit="this.onsubmit= function(){return false;}">


<table class='loginTbl' border='1' align="center" cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3' width='60%'>
   <input type="hidden" name="hdnrequesttype" value="1" />
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <td colspan='3' align="middle" class='loginHead'>Login</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody class='loginBody'>

   <tr>
    <td class='loginBodyTd1' nowrap="nowrap">Employee ID</td>
    <td class='loginBodyTd2'><input type='text' name='txtmemberid' id='txtmemberid' value='' class='loginTextBox' size='30' maxlength='8'/></td>
    <td class='loginBodyTd3' rowspan='2'><input type="submit" class="goclearbutton" value="  Go  "></td>
   </tr><input type='hidden' name='txtmemberpwd' id='txtmemberpwd' value='' />

   </tbody>

   <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' class='loginFoot'>
            <font class='loginRed'>New Visitor?</font>

            <a href="mailto:admin@libsys.co.in?subject=New Registration&body=New Registartion Request">Send</a> your registration request to library !

           </td>
       </tr>
   </tfoot>

   </table>
   </form>
```

I came to know that I may need to set cookie , so the cookie name in the landing page is JSESSIONID(in case that's reqd). And I discovered that once I successfuly log in then I would have to use beautifulSoup to get the details. Please help me how to combine these pieces together.

Comment: short answer - use mechanize or selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this,

```
import requests

response = requests.post("http://14.139.251.99:8080/jopacv06/html/checkouts/memberlogin", data = {'txtmemberid': '1'})

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_code = response.text
// Do whatever you want to do further with this HTML now.
```

Comment: I tried it with a valid id but its showing the html of some other page again and again.

Comment: Did you try hitting the URL from some other tool ? Do you get same result ? You can use tools like `Postman REST client` chrome plugin...

Comment: Thanks , I just included 'txtmemberpwd'=' ' in the data dictionary and it worked for me.